# unlimited reverse Geocoding request

Tags: ios, performance, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I have implemented an application which can import a GPX file and it contains many lat/long coordinates (several hundred).

My application performs a reverse geocoding for each lat/long. I want to display in a tableview all lat/long with their address (which will be ordered by country and town).

I'm performing only one geocoding request at a time (like it's described in Apple's documentation of reverseGeocodeLocation() in Core Location.
When I get the answer of a geocoding request then I request the next one and then until I have resolved all my Lat/Long.

Unfortunately when I have resolved around 40 Lat/Long, the reverseGeocodeLocation() raises an error (CLError.network) and then I need to wait 60 seconds before the resolve the next ones etc...

I have several questions:
 - Is there a way to go faster? because if I have 800 lat/long it will takes around 20 minutes (800/40) * 60 = 1200 seconds (it's very long for an App running on a iPhone)
 - Even if I don't perform improvements on the rate, is there a risk that if I have many users then Apple will forbid my App because the number of Geocoding request will be too high?

Thanks for your feedback
Regards,

Sebastien

Comment: The docs say "Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action".  So I would say sending 800 requests for a single user action definitely runs the risk of you getting rejected for abusing the geocoding APIs.

Comment: I agree but do you see others options (free)?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is the GPX file static or will it be changing for every user/download? If static, then maybe just reverse geocode all the coords beforehand?

Alternately, look for a different service to do reverse geocoding.

Comment: It will not be static, every user may import its own GPX files. 
The only solution I have found is to perform the reverse geocoding only when the user will touch a pin on the map. Only one at a time will be resolved and it will be compliant with Apple's rule. 

In the table where all entries are displayed I will display only lat/long for entries not resolved and then full address for entries that have been resolved. If I want to resolve all lat/long the only solution is to pay for a service and I cannot afford for my app

I would prefer to have a better solution for my users but no choice